# How to change Variables with Coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have the following code in which I want to change a Variables

```
    var allList : ArrayList<NotesEntity> = ArrayList<NotesEntity>()
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        allList = database.getNotesDao().getAll() as ArrayList<NotesEntity>
        Log.v("1","" + allList.size)
    }
    Log.v("2","" + allList.size)
```

after `allList = database.getNotesDao().getAll() as ArrayList<NotesEntity>`allList.size is 2,I Log allList.size，content was

> V/1: 0
>
> V/2: 2

How to let `Log.v("2","" + allList.size)` been V/2: 2

Comment: When you launch a coroutine it gets sent off to the dispatcher to be run on another thread while the current thread continues. Since you are immediately logging the value of `allList` on the original thread, it most likely will occur before the coroutine even starts.

Comment: How to let it do after thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `database.getNotesDao().getAll()` function is a `suspend` function, you can use `Dispatchers.Main` as a coroutine context:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    var allList : ArrayList<NotesEntity> = database.getNotesDao().getAll() as ArrayList<NotesEntity>
    // update UI or do other stuff with `allList`
}
```

Note, however, that using [`GlobalScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/index.html) is discouraged, use appropriate `CoroutineScope`.

Another tip: you can try to use `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` (In this case I also suspect `database.getNotesDao().getAll()` is a `suspend` function):

```
var allList : ArrayList<NotesEntity> = ArrayList<NotesEntity>()
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) { // launch the coroutine immediately
    allList = database.getNotesDao().getAll() as ArrayList<NotesEntity>
    Log.v("1","" + allList.size)
}
Log.v("2","" + allList.size)
```

---

UPDATE:

If your `database.getNotesDao().getAll()` function isn't a `suspend` function you can try next approach:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    var allList : ArrayList<NotesEntity> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // runs code in background thread
        database.getNotesDao().getAll() as ArrayList<NotesEntity> 
    }
    // update UI or do other stuff with `allList`
}
```

Comment: I try your code and it put Error
`Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`

Comment: I guess marking function `database.getNotesDao().getAll()` as `suspend` will solve the problem: `suspend fun getAll()...`

Comment: Also please check my answer, i've added another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can join on the job returned from calling launch if you are under a coroutine, otherwise create new coroutine and join on that job, then do the further tasks. But you should do the tasks in the launch itself, why do you want to take result out of coroutine?

**When you are inside a coroutine, just simply call join():**

```kotlin
var allList : ArrayList<NotesEntity> = ArrayList<NotesEntity>()
val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    allList = database.getNotesDao().getAll() as ArrayList<NotesEntity>
    Log.v("1","" + allList.size)
}
job.join()
Log.v("2","" + allList.size)
```

Otherwise you can do join on another coroutine :P, there's no other way you can wait for a coroutine when not being in coroutine (however you could do a runBlocking, but that will block the thread).

```kotlin
var allList : ArrayList<NotesEntity> = ArrayList<NotesEntity>()
val job = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    allList = database.getNotesDao().getAll() as ArrayList<NotesEntity>
    Log.v("1","" + allList.size)
}
GlobalScope.launch {
    job.join()
    Log.v("2","" + allList.size)
}
```